# Browse image in local disk,set in grid view column and to store c:inetpub\wwwroot?

Tags: c#

Browse image, and image set in grid view column then to store `c:/inetpub/wwwroot`

Error message:

> Access to the path is denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a Visual Studio as a Administrator.